# How to decode string with unicode in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I have the following line:

```
%7B%22appVersion%22%3A1%2C%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22web-experience-app%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22rootURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22
```

Expected Result:

```
{"appVersion":1,"modulePrefix":"web-experience-app","environment":"production","rootURL":"/","
```

You can check it out [here](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php).
What I tried:

```py
foo = '%7B%22appVersion%22%3A1%2C%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22web-experience-app%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22rootURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22'

codecs.decode(foo, 'unicode-escape')

foo.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

This does not work. What other options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is urlencoded.  You can convert it  by reversing the urlencoding.

```
from urllib import parse

s = '%7B%22appVersion%22%3A1%2C%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22web-experience-app%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22rootURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22'

unquoted = parse.unquote(s)
unquoted
'{"appVersion":1,"modulePrefix":"web-experience-app","environment":"production","rootURL":"/","'
```

This looks like part of a larger JSON string.  The complete object can be de-serialised with `json.loads`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way, without using a ```urllib```?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I wouldn't be too difficult to write your own decoder, using the information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), but given that urllib is in the standard library it seems rather pointless.